# Angular 2: Block GET request on a URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have URLs as `http://www.localhost:4200/profile` and `http://www.localhost:4200/editProfile`. Both URLs are served to a logged in user. Now I want the accessibility of `/editProfile` only through the navigation menu available and not by directly writing the URL on address bar and pressing enter. If the user does so, he is redirected to `/profile` path.

Something similar to allowing POST on `/editProfile` but no GET.

Can it be achieved using CanActivate available at the routes module?

Thanks

Comment: Why is it ok if the user goes to that route via the navigation menu, but no directly via browser address bar?

Comment: business requirements.

Comment: Secondly, apart from this there are many such scenarios where it might be of use. For Example if there is summary page of a shopping cart then you don't want the user to visit it directly without going to checkout pages. right?

Comment: I wouldn't block direct navigation in my app. An `AuthGuard` that checks whether the user is logged in should be enough.  I wrote up an answer for you though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sumit. I asked you for the purpose because the way I solve that problem is not by preventing user from navigating via the address bar.  Doing so will break things for users who should have legitimate access to that page. If a user is logged in already, why should she not be allowed to directly access `edit profile` page?  It will also break things when the user tries to use forward and back navigation buttons in her browser and will make for a very frustrating experience I think.

If you still want to do it...

You can use `CanActivate` in your route definition

```
path: 'editProfile',
component: EditProfileComponent,
canActivate:[EditProfileGuard]
```

`EditProfileGuard` is a service that will allow navigation only if a flag is set to true

```
@Injectable()
export class EditProfileGuard implements CanActivate {

    //must be set to true for navigation to succeed
    allow = false;

    canActivate(){
        if(this.allow){
            this.allow = false;
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

If the user navigates via browser address bar, she will be denied access because `allow` is false.

When user clicks a link in your nav menu, set `allow` to true before you send her to the new route

```
import {EditProfileGuard} from '...'
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
...
export class MyComponent{

    constructor(private guard:EditProfileGuard, private router:Router){}

    //execute this when link is clicked
    goToProfile(){
        //so navigation will be allowed
        this.guard.allow = true; 
        this.router.navigateByUrl('editProfile');
    }
}
```

Remember to add the service to the `providers` array of your `AppModule`.

**In response to your comments below:**

I would make a `checkoutID` a required parameter to the summary page, so the route definition would be `/summary/:id` The link to the checkout page (or a url the user saved) would have the `id`, and the summary component can use that `id` to retrieve and display details.

If a user who has not checked out tries to navigate directly to the summary page, the `id` will be missing and the navigation will fail.

In `ngOnInit` for the summary component, I would validate the `id`, so that if a user invents a fake `id` and tries to navigate, I can redirect instead of loading the component.

This will allow legitimate users to navigate directly, and forward/back navigation to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BeetleJuice, but how about the second scenario i mentioned, would you agree on maintaining each such route using a gaurd? 

Second Scenario: if there is summary page of a shopping cart then you don't want the user to visit it directly without going to checkout pages.

Comment: I would suggest you to check out this page as reference https://www.flipkart.com/viewcart . Add an item to cart and proceed to purchase, now without going to cart try visiting this link https://www.flipkart.com/checkout/init . It doesn't allows you the same. Hope this explains in a better way

Comment: @SumitAgarwal I've added a paragraph to my answer.  If you choose to use my ideas, don't forget to select and upvote the answer.  Good luck.

Comment: but what if the user edit the generated javascript and hardcoded the "allow" variable to always be "true"?

Comment: @arvstracthoughts Ultimately, the user can take control of whatever Javascript does on the page. If a user would go through the trouble to do this, she can change everything about what your app does in the browser. If you're trying to keep valuable information from the user, it should be done server-side; don't ever send that info to the browser.  JavaScript block is just for convenience, so the user doesn't see a blank page where the profile or the cart summary would be.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer @BeetleJuice. You can in fact take advantage of the fact that an external route event will reinstantiate your app, thus clearing all variables ([Angular Routing Gotchas](https://coeurdecode.com/web%20development/2017/10/01/angular-routing-gotchas/)).

Going a step further, you can create a second service to abstract out the "internal" routing:

***internal-router.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class InternalRouter {

  private _isNavigationAllowed = false;
  get isNavigationAllowed(): boolean {
    return this._isNavigationAllowed;
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.runNavigation(() => this.router.navigate(commands, extras));
  }

  navigateByUrl(url: string | UrlTree): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.runNavigation(() => this.router.navigateByUrl(url));
  }

  private runNavigation(navigation: () => Promise<boolean>): Promise<boolean> {
    this._isNavigationAllowed = true;
    return navigation()
      .then(success => {
        this._isNavigationAllowed = false;
        return Promise.resolve(success);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this._isNavigationAllowed = false;
        return Promise.reject(e);
      });
  }
}
```

***internal-only.guard.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { InternalRouter } from './internal-router.service';

@Injectable()
export class InternalOnlyGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private internalRouter: InternalRouter) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.internalRouter.isNavigationAllowed) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');  // Or other logic
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Things to note:

- The guard uses the real router when redirecting to avoid an infinite loop in some situations (depending on your routes, redirects, and other guards)
- `runNavigation()` in the router service takes a cold promise, so it doesn't start routing until it's ready.

I found this approach nice because `InternalRouter` is solely responsible for its own state.