# Angular7: how to prevent navigation via URL?

Tags: angular

In my Angular app, I would like users to be able to load it from root url (`/`) only.
If the user tries any other url in the browser, he should be redirected to root url immediately.

However, class redirections like `this.router.navigate(['some-url'])` in the app should work correctly

How can I do this?

For now, I saw `NavGuard` in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145779/angular-2-block-get-request-on-a-url) but maybe there is simpler trick to make this.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just add in your app.module constructor a router.navigateByUrl('/') therefore no matter what they do, when the app loads they go there. Or you could create a variable in your sessionStorage that holds a value, such as `sessionStorage.setItem('userOnline', true)`, and then check for that value OnInit. Since session storage is destroyed on tab-close, then they can route-navigate if putting any route directly over the broswer navbar, but ONLY if they already have the app loaded. App loading would redirect to '/'.

Any variation of this idea, could and should work. Do ask me if you are lost though!

Comment: Thanks, this is an excellent answer! Adding a `router.navigateByUrl('/')` in app.module constructor works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is a bad practice imho

You should try this routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { BarComponent } from '@components/bar.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: BarComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class FooRoutingModule { }
```